# Using SFSafariViewController instead of ASWebAuthenticationSession/SFAuthenticationSession for OAuth

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, sfsafariviewcontroller, sfauthenticationsession, aswebauthenticationsession

Our user experience team does not like the consent popup every time login page is opened. Also, we are looking to customize the look of the browser window presented when OAuth is implemented using `ASWebAuthenticationSession/SFAuthenticationSession`.

For the reasons above, I am thinking to change the implementation and use `SFSafariViewController` directly for Authentication.

Although I did not find any reference for this, but I am worried if using `SFSafariViewController` for OAuth would give problem in Appstore submission as Apple has already provided a way for it in form of `ASWebAuthenticationSession/SFAuthenticationSession`? Does anyone has a view on it?

Comment: SHN, were you able to make this work?

Comment: @CaseyPerkins, Sorry we did not go ahead with SFSafariViewController, used ASWebAuthenticationSession and the UI team approved the consent popup.

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 11 SFSafariViewController no longer shares cookies so I'm afraid that's not possible.

Comment: Sorry, I am not very clear, SFVC no longer shares cookies - this means SSO won't work but we can still open SFVC in app and get auth token. My concern is: whether submission to AppStore will be of any problem if implementing OAuth with SFSafariViewController instead of new SFAuthenticationSession?